# Which file is used for password related modules in Ubuntu 20.04? /etc/pam.d/common-password or /etc/pam.d/common_password

Tags: 20.04, password

Wanted to which file is used for password related modules in Ubuntu 20.04? /etc/pam.d/common-password or /etc/pam.d/common_password. Its to verify that null passwords cannot be used

Comment: I would assume a directory ending in `.d` will parse ALL files inside it so ... both?! and the last one parsed wins if there are duplicates. edit: https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d see `/etc/pam.conf` for the services used.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the package index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=focal&keywords=common-password), it is `common-password`:

| File | Packages |
| --- | --- |
| `/usr/share/pam/common-password` | [`libpam-runtime`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libpam-runtime) |

(The maintainer scripts of the package copy the above file to `/etc/pam.d` and perform other changes on it based on `debconf` configuration.)